# convert sqlite database to nsdata and back

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsdata, nsfilemanager

I converted `sqlite` file to `NSData` to save it in document directory. Now I'm converting it to `sqlite` file and saving that file in document directory, but the new `sqlite` file is not a valid sqlite file and code doesn't read data from it now. Below is the code I'm using to convert `NSData` to sqlite file:

```
-(void)openDataBase{
// First, test for existence.
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Demo.sqlite"];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];

if (success)
{
    NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:writableDBPath];
    NSString * _key = @"111";
    NSData *decryptedData = [data AES256DecryptWithKey:_key];
  [fileManager createFileAtPath:writableDBPath contents:decryptedData attributes:nil];
    return;
}
// The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Demo.sqlite"];

NSData *SqliteData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:defaultDBPath];

NSString * _key = @"111";

NSData *encryptedData = [SqliteData AES256EncryptWithKey:_key];

success= [fileManager createFileAtPath:writableDBPath contents:encryptedData attributes:nil];
if (!success)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);} }
```

What is wrong in my code, I think all time i am creating new sqlite file but how to solve this problem?
 
Can anybody help me how I can convert `NSData` to sqlite file.
Should I write sqlite file in library and then access it from there ?
But every update would decrypt sqlite file, i have to decrypt it.

Comment: upvote for trying things in new way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file exists already, your code will decrypt and overwrite it. If it doesn't, you write an encrypted copy of a default database to the disk. So by default you have an encrypted file which will not be usable.

Comment: Hi Wain, thanks..!!! Here my requirement is to use single encrypted file but when i need to insert/update in sqlite file it should decrypt so that i can update it with new data then again it should be encrypted, i enable filesharing on/true in plist so i want if user try to access this file from iTunes she will be able to access it but won't able to edit it.

Comment: You could store each piece of data encrypted in the SQLite store instead of encrypting the whole file. Saving an unencrypted file to disk even temporarily kind of defeats the point...

Answer (score 0):

To use Sqlite in app i store it in Library sandbox (NSLibraryDirectory) of app, then i always keep it in document directory after encryption, and i note file modification time (NSFileModificationDate) in lib sqlite when time would be modified, i replace the library database from Doc directory DB after decryption(AES256DecryptWithKey:), and in this way i implemented it successfully in the app. 
it's nice experience. 

Happy coding….!!!!!!